# Fog wont appear

Tags: volumetrics, shader-nodes

Im new to blender and I tried adding fog to a scene using Eevee. The way I did it was by  adding a cube to the scene and in the shading I did [image]

even though I increase or decrease density, nothing happens. I tried the same for a previous project I did and it worked fine.Please help

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: To add to above comment. Upload to https://pasteall.org/blend/